# Local Notifications can not be used in ionic 3.8+

Tags: ionic3, angular5, ionic-native

While I'm trying to use local notifications plugin in **ionic3+**, there are no errors showing in editor but building of application is not working.

There are 6 major issues in plugin.

I have tried everything but failed to build application whenever the Local-Notifications is installed.

Comment: Can you show us the error stacktrace ?

i think you have to update your sdk version

Comment: ```G:\ionic\dexterio\platforms\android\src\de\appplant\cordova\plugin\notification\Manager.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
import android.app.NotificationChannel
  symbol:   class NotificationChannel
  location: package android.app



6 errors
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problems. I cannot get it to build with local notifications, even using the older versions of local notifications. Even tried on a clean new app. DId you have any luck?

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late for this to be helpful.

I had a similar issue. The NotificationChannel was added in Android API level 26.  Because I was using a cordova version that targets a lower API level, it throws the "cannot find symbol" error when compiling.

I downloaded the SDK Platform (API Level 26) in Android SDK Manager. I ran the below commands to upgrade the project to Cordova Android 6.3.0, the build was successful after that.

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@6.3.0
```